# CentOS7 Python Security Update

Tags: centos, python

I would like to know how to install a security update for Python 2.7.5.

I was notified that my CentOS 7 Python version had a security patch update. The details are here:

https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2018-July/022964.html

I have scoured the internet trying to look for ways to install that specific patch, but I couldn't find.

I have tried `sudo yum update python-2.7.5-69.el7_5.x86_64.rpm`, but you can probably tell that I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks Goro, that's actually what I'm most curious about. If I download the packages to the computer, can I sudo yum install ____ them, and it will replace the current ones on the machine?

Comment: No need for yum. the packages are `rpm` files you can use `rpm ` and the flag `U` and `rpm` will do the upgrade. Please see below and let me know ;-)

Comment: why not just a `yum -y update` or `yum -y update python`?

Comment: it works as well

Comment: I tried doing that, but then it states "no packages marked for update"

Comment: You mean `yum` told you that ;-0

Comment: Yep :). I'm trying your method right now Goro. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: No problem, but be sure to feed the correct URL of the packages to `wget` Regarding `yum` you should use the command as follows `yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work properly with the least amount of work, you really should make sure your YUM repositories are configured properly.  You should not need to use any non-official repositories unless the package you seek is not included.

The Python security update [`python-2.7.5-69.el7_5.x86_64.rpm`](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-69.el7_5.x86_64.rpm) is indeed located on the official CentOS 7 mirrors, so if your YUM cannot locate and install that package then something is misconfigured in your repositories.

Please check the contents of the files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, make sure that the `[updates]` repository is enabled and pointing to official CentOS 7 mirrors.  Also make sure that any non-official repositories are set at a lower priority then official repositories or disabled altogether unless you really know what you are doing.

If the YUM repositories are configured properly, you can get the security update by simply running `yum install python`.  If that still is not working, you should post the contents of the files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and the output of `yum info python` for others to help more effectively.

Comment: Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Including mirror: ftp.upcnet.ro
Including mirror: archive.linux.duke.edu
Including mirror: mirrors.kernel.org
Including mirror: mirrors.tongji.edu.cn
Including mirror: ius.mirror.constant.com
Including mirror: mirror.amsiohosting.net
Including mirror: ius.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
Including mirror: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
 * ius: ftp.upcnet.ro
Installed Packages
Name        : python
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.7.5
Release     : 68.el7
Size        : 79 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base

Comment: I checked the updates centos-x86_64-os.repo, and it has look modified by my company to include mirrors of their own.

Comment: How can I add the official centos mirror? Do I need to add it by using Yum's config-manager, or do I need to add it somehow to the centos-x86_64-os.repo?

Comment: The official `[base]` and `[updates]` YUM repositories are by default configured in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` provided by the `centos-release` RPM package.  If your company intentionally changed these to point elsewhere, you should really be asking them why before making changes as they may have a valid policy reason to not use those.  If your company is hosting their own YUM repositories, make sure they are updated with the most recent security updates.

Comment: Yep, this ended up being the answer. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

According to [yum man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html)

```
 install
              Is  used  to install the latest version of a package or group of packages while ensuring that all depen\u2010
              dencies are satisfied.  (See Specifying package names for more information) If no  package  matches  the
              given  package  name(s),  they are assumed to be a shell glob and any matches are then installed. If the
              name starts with @^ then it is treated as an environment group (group install @^foo), an @ character and
              it's treated as a group (plain group install).

              If  the  name  starts with a "-" character, then a search is done within the transaction and any matches
              are removed. Note that Yum options use the same syntax and it may be necessary to use  "--"  to  resolve
              any possible conflicts.

              If  the  name is a file, then install works like localinstall. If the name doesn't match a package, then
              package "provides" are searched (e.g. "_sqlitecache.so()(64bit)") as are filelists (Eg. "/usr/bin/yum").
              Also note that for filelists, wildcards will match multiple packages.

              Because  install does a lot of work to make it as easy as possible to use, there are also a few specific
              install commands "install-n", "install-na" and "install-nevra". These only work on package names, and do
              not process wildcards etc.

       update If run without any packages, update will update every currently installed package.  If one or more pack\u2010
              ages or package globs are specified, Yum will only update the listed packages.  While updating packages,
              yum will ensure that all dependencies are satisfied. (See Specifying package names for more information)
              If the packages or globs specified match to packages which are not currently installed then update  will
              not  install them. update operates on groups, files, provides and filelists just like the "install" com\u2010
              mand.
```

Your `yum` command should be:

```
sudo yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
```

You can also use the command `rpm`, download the package using`wget``

```
wget https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-updates-x86_64/
```

Then, install the package:

```
rpm -Uvh python-2.7.5-69.el7_5.x86_64.rpm
Flag -U will do the upgrade for you
```

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm still confused. When I try to wget, it downloads an html webpage. I can't actually find a download link on "https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-updates-x86_64/python-libs-2.7.5-69.el7_5.x86_64.rpm.html"

If I try to follow the instructions on the website itself, yum will inform me "No packages marked for update".

If I try to go the wget way, it will fail on the rpm... since it's a .html file. I can't seem to get the rpm link.

Comment: Thanks for your help Goro. I ended up finding it. Now, the two files in particular that had the security issues were both Python and python-libs. I wget them both, and attempted the rpm... but now it's giving me a dependency error. Whenever I try to rpm python-2.7.5, it tells me I need python-libs. Whenever I rpm python-libs, it tells me I need python-2.7.5... Is there a way I can do both at once?

Comment: Okay, but that's weird. If I do yum install python, it tells me that there are no marked packages for update.

Comment: Tried that, it stated "nothing to do"

Comment: Also, you can find all the python rpms including python libs here http://mirror.clarkson.edu/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: I think I may see the problem now. My current version of python is -68... and I'm attempting to install python -69. But, it's not allowing me.